# ACCESS: Move Data --> Access Database keeps wanting to split

Tags: ms-access

I have an ACCESS database that I'm using to test migration to SQL Server.  It has one local table; no linked tables, forms, queries, or reports. One site said to use the open the Database Tools tab, and click the Access Database icon in the Move Data group.  When I do, it tells me that the database must be split.  How do I let ACCESS know that the database has been split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The move data features up to Access 2010 ALSO had a feature to move data to SQL server. However, due to SQL server always changing and having new versions that come out at "different" times then ms-access?

the feature was deprecated, and versions of Access after 2010 don't have the move to sql server anymore.

If this is just say a simple single table, then it you can use SQL server studio to import the table. (but, you lose PK settings, and indexing, and relationships (assumes you have more then one table and related tables).

If you looking to migrate a lot of data, and a lot of tables?

Then it is high recommended that you use the Sql Server Migration Assistant for Access. (SSMAA).

It is a separate download. You can find SSMAA here:

Information on this tool, and download links can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-ver16

While the tool has a learning curve, it is well worth the efforts for any type of serious data migration from Access to SQL server.